# I have Invalid syntax in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to this forum thingy and python. Please be gentle.
I have tried to fix it but it still doesn't work. I am really nervous. Help.

```
print('Print')
input('make space by pressing space')
print('Thanks for the space, space, space, spaceeeeeeee.')
input('read this? (press to continue)')
print('also thanks for your time')
print('What is your age')
age = input()
#age
print('In 42 years you will be:' + str(int(age) + 42) + ' years old')
print('Also, did you read "Hitchhikers guide to the galaxy"?')
print('Anwser with "true" or "false"')
hgttg = input()
#if's are coming
if hgttg == 'true'
   print('Ah, you earned my respect')
   input('good (press to continue)')
   else
   print('Ok, you can read it another day, you are still conversing with 
   me')
   input('this time no respect (press to continue)')
   #water adventure   
   print('Can you bring me a glass of water, please?')
   print('Again, anwser with either "true" or "false"')
   boolwater = input()
   if boolwater == 'true'
   print('Thanks!')
   input('press to continue')
   else
   print('I will go get it myself ')
   input('youve angered me (press to continue)')

    print('Thanks for talking to me, and see you another time!')
    input('Press to exit')
```

Comment: You are missing the colons `:` in your if and else lines, and your indentation is off, at least in what you've posted.

Comment: It's helpful if you also post the entire error message.

Comment: Is there a specific line giving the problem? As it stands, the code looks to have formatting issues, e.g. if/else statements aren't indented, and `print('Ok, you can read it another day,...` runs over a line. These might be the problem9s) but maybe pasting the code into the question went wrong. Which line is giving you the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your [indentations](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) are off and missing `:` colons at the end of your [if/ else statements](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/if-elif-else)

```
if hgttg == 'true':
    print('Ah, you earned my respect')
    input('good (press to continue)')
else:
    print('Ok, you can read it another day, you are still conversing with me')
    input('this time no respect (press to continue)')
    #water adventure   
    print('Can you bring me a glass of water, please?')
    print('Again, anwser with either "true" or "false"')
    boolwater = input()
    if boolwater == 'true':
        print('Thanks!')
        input('press to continue')
    else:
        print('I will go get it myself ')
        input('youve angered me (press to continue)')
print('Thanks for talking to me, and see you another time!')
input('Press to exit')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your syntax is that you need to use spaces or a tab for writing the body.

```
if conditions :
    print("conditions are true")
else :
    print("they are not true")
```

As you can see I used spaces to separate the body.